# Adobe Target IP obfuscation for all 4 octets

Tags: adobe, target, adobe-analytics

So basically, in Adobe Target you can obfuscate client IP address's last octet as explained in: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/tnt/help/c_privacy.html

However, in some countries, this is not good enough. Which means we need to obfuscate the entire IP address (4 octets rather than just last octet).

In another word, let's say we just don't want to be able to identify which company the user logged in from when collecting their data for analytical purposes.

I wonder if there is a way we can do this in Adobe Target?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but in Germany you do not need to obfuscate the whole IP.  The decision by the "Düsseldorfer Kreis" (the conference of the data protection officials of the German federal countries) demands "Anonymisierung der IP-Adresse (z.B. durch Kürzen oder Überschreiben der IP-Adresse)" that is "anonymizing by shortening or overwriting". They would not have bothered with the "or" if they had required to delete the IP address completely.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question.

Comment: To expand on what @EikePierstorff mentioned vs. you updating your question to be more generic "some countries".. I'm not a legal source but my understanding is there are no countries that require full IP obfuscation.  Adobe is a global enterprise level tool, and is generally on top of such things.. but lets say you want to do it anyway for your own reasons.  Adobe does not offer a way for you to anonymize the full IP address yourself.  I'm not sure that they will do it for you on your end, but you can certainly contact clientcare@adobe.com and ask!

Comment: also just going to throw it out there that i mostly work with global enterprise level clients and so far none of their legal/privacy departments have required full IP obfuscation to comply with anything.

Comment: I don't want to mention my employer, this is a requirement from a "global enterprise level company". I was there at the adobe summit a few days ago but didn't get an answer and I would love to know if there is a Adobe internet community that I can join so that I will stop asking Adobe specific questions here?

Answer (score -1):

I am a product marketing manager for Adobe Target. You may request our client care to obfuscate the full IP addresses of ALL your visitors. Please visit our help document [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/implement-target/before-implement/privacy/privacy.html#concept_639482A343DB4963A6144378E1D8D7F0) to learn more.